# full width navigation - Industry theme

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, slider, meta

I know there are many posts that have similar questions but after reading a fair few I still don't feel closer to being able to achieve a full width header.

My site is http://f24.f99.myftpupload.com/

I added to .container - width: 100%, margin: 0px, padding: 0px 
- which pulled the navigation full width like I wanted but it also pulled all of my page content out to the edge of the window which I don't want.
Is there any easy/possible way to get the page content to stay pushed in off the edge but pull the navigation full width?

I am also having an issue with my meta slider on the Research page - it sits within a tabbed container on the page - it was working perfectly fine then I shuffled some on top of others and changed their section ID and now when first loaded it pushes all of the content in to a single column, one letter per line, but if you refresh or inspect the page it puts it back as it should be. 
I have no idea what is causing this or how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: container is a bootstrap class, change with container-fluid for full width.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem open header.php file in your theme folder and put out from container div the navigation div. What i saw with inspector it is the one with the `class="nav-copy"` so the structure of your html should be:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="clearfix header-top">...</div>
   <div class="show-small">...</div>
</div>
<div class="nav-copy">...</div>
```

For the second problem its unclear sorry.